# Understanding owner groups of a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, debian

I am having some problems understanding how users and groups permissions work in Linux.

The command I am trying to launch is the following:

```
ln -nfs /home/mmarteau/wfor.it/releases/release_folder /var/www/my_website
```

and I get the following error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/my_website': Permission denied
```

I have a user `mmarteau` that belongs to the `www-data` group:

```
$ groups mmarteau
mmarteau : mmarteau www-data
```

Then, I made the folder `/var/www` user and owner group to `www-data`:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 May 14 22:58 www
```

So, as far as I understand, the user has rights to read, write and execute. The group has the same rights.

So, what am I missing? Of course, I could sudo to make this operation but I don't want to, I would like to understand how this work.

If I pass the right to `write` to `others` (`drwxrwxrwx`) it also works, but I don't think that this is clean at all..

Don't hesitate to tell me if I am not giving all the information necessary for you to answer my question.

Comment: What groups does the user see if he types the `id` command?

Comment: I am sorry to have posted in the wrong place, would you like me to delete my post? Here is the id command: `uid=1001(mmarteau) gid=1001(mmarteau) groups=1001(mmarteau) `

Comment: Notice that the `www-data` group isn't listed. Did you just add him to the group? He needs to logout and log back in to get the group permissions.